# Tapku calendar Add Events

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.2, tapku

I am using `Tapku library` in my app. It works fine for me.. but my point is `How can I add different Images on different Events on Calendar.`

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4):

You can open the bundle of tapku library which contains images and you can replace the images.

Comment: you mean that place https://github.com/JPluto/tapkulibrary/tree/master/src/TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar

Answer (score 2):

The images are found at: "**TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today**" or you could make the path point to one of your own images.

```
 self.selectedImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today Selected Tile.png")];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own image also, Try this code

```
UIImage *tile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"ownImage.png")];
```