# iOS: Tapku calendar library Color Coding Dates

Tags: objective-c, ios, tapku

I'm implementing `Tapku calendar` in my `iOS` app and I want to change the color of a certain **date/tile** to **RED/any** other color based on some information. I'm fine with either changing the full tile (but not surrounding ones, of course) or the marks that are placed on the tile. Others have asked this, but I have not yet found a response or a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try following links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288689/1099453 for changing tile colors.

And an example is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65213224/CalDemo%202.zip).(Customization of tapku calendar)